Is there a way to show full errors in production builds for Next.js, instead of ambiguous ones?
I am working on a project with NextJs (14.1.0). I'm attempting to make it easier for developers and testers in our team to debug issues found in the test environment.
I made an 'error.tsx' file to catch any unexpected errors thrown in components. There I show a stack trace if we are in the Test or Accept environments.
This works locally, but in a production build this turns into an error with: "The specific message is omitted in production builds to avoid leaking sensitive details."
Is there a way to disambiguate this error only on test and not on accept or production, and thus make it easier for to the tester to tell what went wrong?

How do you run your environments? Do you use proper NODE_ENV values?

@Anton Yes, I have environment variables. No, I don't use NODE_ENV. I'm trying to find a way to run a production build in which I could still see details on errors.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
